# "Does anyone recommend a place to go in New York?"

Tags: grammar

"Does anyone recommend a place to go in New York?"

can "a place to go" be a variable?

"Does anyone have a recommendation for a place to go in New York?" sounds better, but is the above sentence grammatically legal?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as ‘illegal’ in matters of grammatical usage.  I should say a more common way of saying it might be

> **Can** anyone recommend a place to go in New York?

But ‘does’ works.  Similarly, I might think the sentence unclear as its stands.  Does it mean ‘a place to *stay*, or a place to *visit*, something else?  But unclear sentences are not thereby ungrammatical.

May be you could say ‘a place to go to’.  But the ellipse is common enough.